# Find parameter so trigonometric equation has real solution

Tags: trigonometry

Find the parameter $m$ so the equation has real solution:
$$(\sin x - m)^2 + (2m \sin x - 1)^2 = 0$$

I tried rewriting it like this:

$$\sin^2 x(1+4m^2) -6m \cdot\sin x + 1 + m^2 = 0$$

And imposing that the discriminant is $\ge 0$, the sum of the roots $\in [-2, 2]$ and the product of the roots $\in [-1, 1]$ (all that because the roots should be in $[-1, 1])$. Still, the answer is $\left\{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any real number $\alpha$, we have $\alpha^2\ge0$ thus we must have both $(\sin x - m)^2=0$ and  $(2m \sin x - 1)^2= 0$.

So we have $\sin x=m$ and $\sin x=\frac{1}{2m}$

This gives $m=\frac{1}{2m}$

And $m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $m=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thank you, it was so visibile... I don't know how i didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $$f(t)=t^2(1+4m^2) -6m \cdot t + 1 + m^2 = 0$$

Your conditions are insufficient.

Sufficient conditions will be :

> $f(1)\cdot f(-1) < 0$ (For one real root)

**Or**

> $-1<\dfrac {\alpha+\beta}{2} <1~~$ (Vertex of parabola lies between $x=-1$ and $x=1$)
>
> **and**
> $~~D \ge 0~~$ (It *has* roots) **and** $f(1),f(-1) >0$

Comment: Why downvote? It is correct.

Comment: Providing that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots and multiplying the first relation in the  OR by 2, you get exactly what I wrote in the question. I haven't downvoted it.

Comment: @Liviu No! It is different.You are missing those cases when One root (Of quadratic in t) is far greater than $1$ while one is lies between $-1$ and $1$. Such that there product is also greater than $1$, sum is also greater than $2$ but It *has* a solution.

Comment: @Liviu Did you check?

Comment: Then, in the OR case, you would have to put  $-1 \le \alpha \cdot \beta \le 1$, right ? And why the first case ? (i mean, why that condition ?)

Comment: @Liviu You asking about $f(1)\cdot f(-1) < 0$?

Comment: You asking about f(1)⋅f(−1)<0f(1)⋅f(−1)<0? Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57132/discussion-between-jaideep-khare-and-liviu).